# Regex: Efficiently matching words that are the same except for last character

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I **efficiently** match words that are the same except for the last letter?

```
data = ['ades', 'adey', 'adhere', 'adherent', 'admin', 'admit', 'adverb', 'advert', 'adipocere', 'adipocerous', 'adjoining', 'adjoint', 'adjudicate', 'adjudication', 'adjunct']
```

The actual data is longer and my implementation below takes too long to run:

```
temp_data = data 
count = 0
matches = {}
while count < len(data):
    for word in data:
        if word[:-1] == data[count][:-1] and data.index(word) != count:
            matches[data[count]] = word
            temp_data.remove(data[count])
            temp_data.remove(word)
    count += 1
print(matches)
```

this correctly prints:

```
{'ades': 'adey', 'advert': 'adverb', 'admin': 'admit'}
```

I'm new to python so any suggestions would be appreciated  :)

Comment: What makes you think regex is the correct tool for this?

Comment: are the pairs supposed to be always together? are there only 2 such strings?

Comment: Are the words already in alphabetical order?  If so, then you need to check only as far as they match to the penultimate letter.  There's no need to run **count** all the way to the end.

Comment: You might want to use a trie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @Falmarri : In case I missed a magic re function that will compare a word to all (formatted) words in the list.

Comment: The dictionary needs to have only the single entry, keyed on the first-listed word?

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri The pairs are not always together. More than two strings match but I am only choosing pairs for now, and ignoring the other ones.

Comment: Why `advert` is the key to dict even though `adverb` comes first in the list? *(I guess typo)*

Comment: Also, you are iterating over a list while modifying it. `temp_data = data` does not create a copy.

Comment: @Prune they are not alphabetical. Although maybe I can make them.. Ill look up how I can do that. Yes only the first-listed, I removed the values from the data to speed it up.

Comment: @Username You will have to just do `data.sort()` to sort the list (i.e. make it alphabetical)

Comment: @Moinuddin Quadri Strange! Not a typo that is the output I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list` is already sorted (else you need to sort it first), and there would be only two such elements in the list following the criterion. You may achieve the result via using *dictionary comprehension* with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) as:

```
>>> data = ['ades', 'adey', 'adhere', 'adherent', 'admin', 'admit', 'adverb', 'advert', 'adipocere', 'adipocerous', 'adjoining', 'adjoint', 'adjudicate', 'adjudication', 'adjunct']

# data.sort()  --> if data is not already sorted
>>> {i: j for i, j in zip(data, data[1:]) if i[:-1]==j[:-1]}
{'admin': 'admit', 'adverb': 'advert', 'ades': 'adey'}
```

PS: I do not think `regex` is the right tool for achieving the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You’re comparing every word against every word and using a check that compares every word every time to make sure you’re not comparing a word against itself for O(n³) time. You can get it to O(n²) time by keeping track of the index in the inner loop:

```
for j, word in enumerate(data):
    if word[:-1] == data[count][:-1] and j != count:
        matches[data[count]] = word
        temp_data.remove(data[count])
        temp_data.remove(word)
```

and then get it to O(n) by just grouping the words by their initial letters:

```
groups = defaultdict(list)

for word in data:
    groups[word[:-1]].append(word)

print(list(groups.values()))
```

which can also be done using [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if your list is sorted:

```
import itertools

def init(word):
    return word[:-1]

print([list(words) for key, words in itertools.groupby(data, init)])
```

Comment: Thank you! @Moinuddin Quadri's solution was faster although your explanations helped me understand the underlying cause better.

Comment: @Username: Faster = less typing, or does it actually perform worse?

Comment: It completes between .2-.4 sec faster.